# A Eurythmics riddle

Tags: riddle

Sweet dreams are made of me,
Who am I, that's the question,
I travel the hands,
and the pockets,
I can sometimes be immaterial

Some of them want to trade me 
Some of them want to be traded with me
Some of them want to play me
Some of them even want to flip me

Hold your head up ...

Comment: thank you, the song will remain stuck in my head for the rest of the day now

Comment: Very nice riddle!

Comment: Thank you, and sorry if it disturb you to have a music stuck in your head, but that music is a good one. Hopefully no one will do a 'let it go' riddle

Comment: @Nank saaaaaaaaaaay, you gave me an awfully wonderfully torturous idea...!

Answer (score 16, accepted):

You are

> a coin

I travel the hands,
and the pockets,

> Buying some groceries

I can sometimes be immaterial

> Cryptocurrencies are immaterial coins

Some of them want to trade me

> Definition of buy

Some of them want to be traded with me

> Working for a salary trades you with coins

Some of them want to play me

> Gambling

Some of them even want to flip me

> Flipping a coin

Comment: You got it! Well play, that was fast

Answer (score 7):

Even if Saeïdryl already find the answer, it also could have been

> The One Ring, from The Lord of the Ring

Sweet dreams are made of me,

> Ok, that's not what we typically call "sweet dreams" but wearing the One Ring make you see the world like ethereal.

Who am I, that's the question,

I travel the hands,

> The One Ring passed from hand to hand : Sauron, Isildur, Déagol...

and the pockets,

> "What have I got in my pocket ?" ~ Bilbo Baggins

I can sometimes be immaterial

> A mortal wearing the One Ring become invisible. The Ring also become invisible.

Some of them want to trade me

> Sméagol tried to get the One Ring from Déagol arguing that it was its birthday... That's some kind of trade...

Some of them want to be traded with me

> Ok, that's a little bit far-fetched but if you consider the One Ring's fire inscription, it say :
>
>  "One Ring to rule them all, One Ring to find them,
>  One Ring to bring them all and in the darkness bind them."
>
>  So we can kind of  consider that all the other rings are some kind of extension of the One Ring.
>  So the nine mortal men have "trade their soul" in exchange of a part of the One Ring power...

Some of them want to play me

> Playing the riddles game with Gollum, Bilbo's last question is about the ring. It's like he is playing his final ace.

Some of them even want to flip me

> Frodo's big question is whether or not will he be able to "flip" the Ring into the lava like he would have done with a coin... Or will he fail like Isildur ?

Comment: That's a totally nice answer! Just a last example to find for "be traded with me" and it's perfect!

Comment: That's a pretty good answer indeed !

Comment: @Saeïdryl Thanks ! I found an example for "be traded with me" but it's a little bit far-fetched !

Comment: But works :) Great job