# A Famous Undertaking

Tags: riddle, knowledge

♪You've known this puzzle for so long,
You know the rules, and so do I.
A full description's what I'm looking for
Of this vehicle for your entertainment

I'm just gonna break it into pieces,
gotta check you understand:

*I'm gonna end, you'll hear,

     with a nice reward

But to take it will take effort.

You'll find I gave my name

     to my ancestor

And I start with an arrival.*

The sky's the limit, or so they say
I keep on going, to the very last border
You can argue who is best in charge,
But that's the game, now it's time to play it!♫

(Bodging together [this puzzle](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/62349/my-prefix-is-food-my-suffix-is-rude) and [this one](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/64290/a-eurythmics-riddle)!)

Comment: Interestingly, the solution to this riddle can be found on [Meta Stack Overflow](http://meta.stackoverfiow.com/q/30803982/3160466).

Comment: I’ve been riddle roll’d

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The answer is

> ENTERPRISE, a (famous) undertaking

---

♪You've known this puzzle for so long,

> The tv series *Star Trek* debuted in 1966, over 50 years ago, and featured weekly episodes of space-faring adventures aboard the USS Starship ***Enterprise***.

You know the rules, and so do I.
A full description's what I'm looking for

> Yup, explaining all the parts of the puzzle is how we do it here.  Ok, here goes ....

Of this vehicle for your entertainment

> The starship *Enterprise*, the famous vehicle of the *Star Trek* series of shows and movies.

I'm just gonna break it into pieces,
gotta check you understand:

> This is a "Riley" style riddle, so the answer will be described piecemeal.

I'm gonna end, you'll hear,
   with a nice reward

> PRISE, which we hear as "Prize", a nice reward. This, we're told, is the end of the word.

But to take it will take effort.

> This might be cluing any number of things:
>  It might refer to the starship *Enterprise* being difficult to capture.
>  It might be that an enterprise is often something hazardous or difficult.
>  Or, probably intended here, is that this line goes with the prior two, because
>    "prise" means "to move or force, especially in an effort to get something open".

You'll find I gave my name
  to my ancestor

> The original Enterprise NCC-1701 from the original television series has gone on to give its name to various other incarnations, including the NCC-1701-C seen briefly in The Next Generation, and the NCC-1701-D, the featured vehicle itself of TNG.  It also was used for the "prequel" series *ENTERPRISE*, both as the name of the show and as the name of the ship, the NX-01.
>
>  Also, a U.S. space shuttle was famously named *Enterprise* (OV-101) following a successful letter-writing campaign by fans of *Star Trek* to give it that name (its original planned name was *Constitution*).

And I start with an arrival.

> ENTER.  This, we're told, is the start of the word.

The sky's the limit, or so they say

> A vague space reference, perhaps.

I keep on going, to the very last border

> Space, the final frontier

You can argue who is best in charge,

> A commentary, most likely, on the debate over who made the best captain - Kirk or Picard.

Comment: Correct!  Although there's one line you don't seem to have spotted the clue in ("But to take it will take effort"), and there's an extra layer to the clue before that ;¬)