# Some of them would say I'm half a duck

Tags: riddle, enigmatic-puzzle

> Some of them would say I'm half a duck 
>   I may be used if you want to try your luck 
>   I inspired your sweetest dreams, will say the most accurate 
>   But for only 15 of them, it was worth a rate 
>   Some of them tend to collect me 
>   Even if I'm usually just worth a few penny

**Ilia L** found the good answer, but I need a good explanation for the 'rate-riming' lines. 
 So here is a hint

> line 3 refers to a famous song from the 80s, maybe I should have added a tag, but it's only my second puzzle on this site so I don't really know how it works

Comment: "Quack Overflow is listening..."

Comment: @Chowzen Unfortunately, I think he is sleeping until april 2019

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You are a

> Coin

Although this is the same answer with Ilia's, I have different reasons

Some of them would say I'm half a duck

> in French, duck sounds not "quack" but ["coin coin"](https://blog.oxforddictionaries.com/2012/04/02/onomatopoeia-in-different-languages/) (I didn't read comment section before, so I didn't know that DevMoutarde has answered it before)

I may be used if you want to try your luck

> Same with Ilia's, you flip a coin to try your luck

I inspired your sweetest dreams, will say the most accurate

> I think it refers to [your last puzzle](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/64290/a-eurythmics-riddle), which the answer is Coin and the question is inspired by a song lyrics "Sweet Dreams" (answer the hint)

But for only 15 of them, it was worth a rate

> There are [15 values in French coins](https://www.lesfrancs.com/value_french_coins.html)

Some of them tend to collect me
Even if I'm usually just worth a few penny

> Some people collect coin (Coin collector) even it has small value in it

Comment: the 15 was about the upvotes of the linked puzzle, but everything else is what I was looking for

Comment: @Nank That seems like a questionable choice of clue given that the vote count can change.

Comment: ah.. I see, but the upvote can change from time to time :)

Comment: @noedne I now, but my previous puzzle is a bit old now, and I was ready to change this one in case the vote count changes

Comment: @Nank I think puzzles on this site are intended to be self-contained and remain solvable for future visitors long after they are initially solved, but the clue will only make sense if you edit this puzzle whenever the other one is upvoted. Just my *two cents* :)

Answer (score 9):

I think you are a:

> A Coin

Some of them would say I'm half a duck

> Canadian dollar coin has a duck on one side

I may be used if you want to try your luck

> You can flip a coin to try your luck

I inspired your sweetest dreams, will say the most accurate

> Some people dream about being rich

But for only 15 of them, it was worth a rate

> something about exchange rates I presume or 15 dollars for a night at a hotel?

Some of them tend to collect me
Even if I'm usually just worth a few penny

> people collect coins and some of them have vary low monetary value

Comment: You got the good answer, but part of your explanation is wrong, the first line is not what i intented, but i could accept this one, but the 'rate-riming' lines are wrong, those are the ones justifying the 'enigmatic-puzzle' tag and I won't accept an answer that does not find these

Comment: Half a duck could be rot13(ovyy)

Comment: @user2397282 No, the real explanation requires some knowledge of french language

Comment: Should possibly tag with [tag:language]?

Comment: @Nank coin coin? says the duck

Comment: @DevMoutarde Yep, that's what I was looking for

Comment: the Canadian dollar does **not** have a duck on it. That is a loon. Hence the nickname loonie for the coin.

Comment: @Nank I tried to make this answer work given that it was the answer to a certain recent similar-sounding question, but I could not explain the clues. I suppose then line 3 refers to the same song?

Comment: @noedne Yep, you are on the right tracks

Answer (score 8):

Are you a

> **HORSESHOE**

Because 
Some of them would say I'm half a duck

> A horseshoe looks like half a circle (duck = zero)

I may be used if you want to try your luck
I inspired your sweetest dreams, will say the most accurate

> Horseshoes are a symbol of luck
>  And are [interpreted as such in dreams](https://www.dreaminterpretations.org/horseshoe/) as well

But for only 15 of them, it was worth a rate

> Game of [horseshoes](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Horseshoes)

Some of them tend to collect me
Even if I'm usually just worth a few penny

> Horseshoe collection as a hobby

Comment: This is a nice answer, but unfortunally, not the one intended

Comment: I'm not following on the "duck = [spoiler]" thing. Why is "duck" a [spoiler]?

Comment: In British English/cricket, a [duck is a zero](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Duck_(cricket)). Cutting a zero in half gives you the shape of [spoiler]. Hope that clarifies, @Flater

Comment: @Phylyp: Yeah I'm from a no-cricket country; that's what I was missing :)

Answer (score 5):

Is it

> **a DECK OF CARDS**

Because

Some of them would say I'm half a duck

> Deck, duck... (half of duck, kind of...)

I may be used if you want to try your luck
I inspired your sweetest dreams, will say the most accurate

> Trying luck in cards ? Or games like Poker... games of luck.
>  I dont know about the dreams tho :(

But for only 15 of them, it was worth a rate

> I was thinking of a 15 cards game... like 'Quinze' (french game)

Some of them tend to collect me
Even if I'm usually just worth a few penny

> Some people collect cards !

My first try here :)

Comment: nice answer, but despite being french, I've never heard of a game called 'Quinze'

Comment: me neither, had to google that :) Appears that the origin is actually Spanish, and it is considered as a forerunner of the French 'Vingt-et-un' (que tu connais :) ) @Nank

Answer (score 3):

You are a:

> Bob?

Some of them would say I'm half a duck

> A synonym for duck is bob.  I would consider ducking something thrown at you to take more time than a bob.  So, I guess a bob might take half the time as a duck...?  ;-)

I may be used if you want to try your luck

> Bobbing for apples or cherries.

I inspired your sweetest dreams, will say the most accurate

> The Eurythmics wrote and sang the song "Sweet Dreams" shortly after the break up of their prior band called "Tourists", who had a member named Robert Görl.  Robert is often shortened to Bob.

But for only 15 of them, it was worth a rate

> In the classic Charles Dickens’s “A Christmas Carol,” Bob Cratchit makes 15 shillings each week.

Some of them tend to collect me

> The UK changed their currency in 1971, so the shilling (aka bob) is no longer in circulation.  As such, they are probably only kept by collectors.

or

> A bobbin might be collected by tailors/seamstresses or DIYers/crafters for various reasons.  I know some people use empty bobbins as flatcar cargo in model railroading.

Even if I'm usually just worth a few penny

> The shilling (bob) was one of the smallest denominations of currency the UK had, so were only worth the equivalent of a few American pennies.  The current pence is also referred to as a penny and is also the smallest denomination for the UK.

Even if this isn't correct, it sound good.... right?

Comment: yep, it isn't the exepected answer, but it still sound good

Answer (score 2):

It is a

> pro-duc-t

**Explanation:**

Some of them would say I'm half a duck

> If you read it phonetically (missing k)

I may be used if you want to try your luck

> All products are made for customer usage

I inspired your sweetest dreams, will say the most accurate

> Sounds like marketing...

But for only 15 of them, it was worth a rate

> I'm stuck here where to get a proper data from but for some expensive **products** like cars or real estate it can be more profitable to take a consumer loan/mortgage

Some of them tend to collect me

> If you have a particular hobby... but we can stand from a mathematics or physics point of view and calculate work (integral over vector **product** of force and movement)

Even if I'm usually just worth a few penny

> like matches (or postage stamps if we are still talking about collecting something)